# Why do I get "can't find crate" when using a module in Rust 2018?

Tags: rust

I have a `lib.rs` file containing:

```
mod bindings {
    // ...
}

pub use bindings::*;
```

What I get from `rustc` is:

```
|  pub use bindings::*;
|          ^^^^^^^^ can't find crate
```

Why does Rust think `bindings` is a crate instead of module?

Comment: Please include which version/toolchain of the compiler you are using.

Comment: The [code you have provided does not produce the error you say it will](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c6efc9041151a780f420bd74aa7fd42c), even when using the 2018 edition. Please review how to create a [MCVE].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be using the 2018 edition of Rust.  There have been a [few changes to paths in `use` declarations](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/edition-guide/rust-2018/module-system/path-clarity.html#changes-to-paths) since the 2015 edition (aka Rust 1.0).  The path after a `use` declaration now always needs to start with a crate name, the `crate` keyword denoting the root of the crate, `self` denoting the current module or `super` denoting the parent module.  So either of these two `use` declarations should work:

```
pub use self::bindings::*;
```

or

```
pub use crate::bindings::*;
```

Comment: Thanks. I left out unintentionally that I'm using 2018 edition.